# 3D line Populating with ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

I'm trying to populate 3d line using ArcGIS API for JavaScript with my ArcGIS online PipeLine url, but somehow I'am not able to populate. I have attached the code.

```
<script>
      require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/SceneView",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/widgets/Legend"
      ], function(Map, SceneView, FeatureLayer, Legend) {

  var map = new Map({
         basemap: "topo-vector",

          ground: "world-elevation"
        });

        var view = new SceneView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,
          zoom: 15,
          center: [103.805699, 1.276566],
           heading: 300,
           tilt: 75
       });
         const options = {
          profile: "quad",
          cap: "round",
          join: "miter",
          width: 5,
          height: 30,
          color: [200, 200, 200],
          profileRotation: "all"
        };

        var renderer = {

          defaultSymbol: {
            type: "polygon-3d",
        symbolLayers: [
                    {
                      type: "path",
                      profile: options.profile,
                      width: options.width,
                      height: options.height,
                      join: options.join,
                      cap: options.cap,
                      anchor: "bottom",
                      profileRotation: options.profileRotation
                    }
                  ]
          }
        };

        const PipelineLayer = new FeatureLayer({
          url:
            "https://services6.arcgis.com/itEfD6Bf5W0iWJuO/arcgis/rest/services/PipeLine1/FeatureServer/0",
          elevationInfo: {
            mode: "relative-to-ground",
            offset: 3
          },
         renderer:renderer
        });
        map.add(PipelineLayer);

      });
    </script>
```